# Handling on click except on radiobutton in the first TD of the cell in the repeater Control

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-events, repeater

I have a repeater with 5 columns. I've used live click on the tr to redirect it to that particular transaction.
Header Columns:  **TranID, TranName, TranType, TranSubType, TranLoc**

Body of the repeater:

1st column:  **Radiobutton & TranID** 
2nd column: TranName 
3rd column: TranType 
4th column: TranSubType 
5th column: TranLoc

In the body of the repeater, I've radiobutton in the first column accompanied by TranID Number. i.e., in first TD I've a radiobutton and a span for showing the TranID value.

Now, I need to handle the live click on tr except for the selection of the radiobutton for that particular transaction. i.e., on click of every td it has to redirect to that transaction page except on selection of Radiobutton.

This link helped me a bit [Click row except for first td](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124600/clicking-a-row-except-for-the-first-td)

```
jQuery('#dyntable tbody tr').live('click', function (evt) {
    var $cell=$(evt.target).closest('td');
        if( $cell.index()>0){
        //redirection to the Transaction Page.
        }
    });
```

In `cell[0]`, I've radiobutton and TranID. Now, on click of TranID the page won't redirect to the Transaction Page. that is my problem. I need to redirect to Transaction Page even on click of TranID of `Cell[0]`.

Could you please help me by suggesting the code or scenario to handle my requirement without disturbing the current design of the repeater.

Comment: Can you post some code. It will help us to answer your question.

Comment: I've updated my query with the lines of code. Any suggestions??